# iOS Facebook SDK 3.2 Check Permissions via Graph Path Request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to check if user has already granted publish permission or not.  if he has not granted permissions before then i navigate him to permissions screen via: **requestNewPublishPermissions**

```
  -(void)checkPermissions
    {
        // Get the most recent status
        [FBRequestConnection
         startWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions"
         completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                             id result,
                             NSError *error) {
             if (!error) { 
                    //This Condition Never Executed

                 if([[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"publish_actions"])
                 {
                     //permissions exist
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     [self openSessionForPublishPermissions];
                 }
                 NSString *permission = [[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"publish_actions"];

                 NSLog(@"permissions data = %@",data);
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"error"); //Control goes to this block
             }
         }];

    }
```

*In code above if(!error) block is never executed and it always returns Error*

Where i'm going wrong? Am i missing something?

Comment: Probably you've already resolved the problem but just in case... To understand what's going wrong it's needed to analyze the error returned. `NSLog(@"error")` is not informative. This code `NSLog(@"%@",error)` would give you much more information about the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can see permissions in the active session. Here is how it's done in the HelloFacebookSample :

```
if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
    // permission does not exist
} else {
    // permission exists
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. FBSession.activeSession.permissions is nil

Comment: Permissions are available if your session has an access token. Have you checked that FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData is not nil, and that its accessToken is set ?

Comment: @Lucas, Yes, Rephael was correct, at least `public_profile` will be available as permission. I think it would not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually checking the permissions, you could check if the session is active and request publish permissions: if the user has already granted the permissions, an additional confirmation dialog will not be posted. See the code sample below:

```
- (void)requestWritePermission:(UIViewController *)viewController channel:(NSString *)channel callback:(void(^)(BOOL success))callback
{   
    if ([FBSession.activeSession isOpen])
    {
        [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                              defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                callback(error == nil);
                                            }];
    }
    else
    {
       // Attempt to request publish permission without read permission. 
    }
}
```

The code is not complete, but should get you started.